# Does my high efficiency furnace need two sources of outside air

Tags: furnace

I had a high efficiency furnace installed. It has a pipe leading to outside for intake. My old furnace had a vent to take air into the firebox. Can I now block that vent since the new furnace has its own?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that vent does not connect to the furnace you can disconnect it and or remove it. You can also use it as fresh air makeup for the home. I have two in my home, the first is 4" opening at the floor by the hot water heater and boiler. This forces the heaters to use mostly outside air saving the climate controlled inside air for people. The second is smaller and connected to the return air. It works great and we do not have drafts.